# RAM-efficient C++ property

Tags: c++, properties

A property is a public data member of a class, which can be accessed by client code. And the owning object receives a notification (in the form of get/set notification callback) whenever the client code reads or modifies the property.

Some languages (like C#) have built-in properties.

I want to create a property for C++ that will be RAM-efficient.
The most obvious way to make a property is something like this:

```cpp
class Super;

struct Prop { 

    Prop( Super * super ) : m_super(*super), m_a(0) {}

    int operator=( int a );
    operator int() const;

    int m_a;
    Super & m_super;

};

struct Super {

    Super() : one(this), two(this) {}

    void onSet() { printf("set"); }
    void onGet() { printf("get"); }

    Prop one;  
    Prop two;

};

int Prop::operator=( int a ) { m_super.onSet(); m_a = a; return a; }
Prop::operator int() const { m_super.onGet(); return m_a; }
```

Trouble is - every property has to keep a pointer to the outer class which I consider costly.

I want to know if there is a more RAM-efficient way to do this?
For example, if all `Super`-classes are generated, is it allowed by the Standard to get a pointer to the outer class from `this` pointer of the property?

Something like this:

```cpp
struct Prop { 

    Prop( uint8_t offset ) : m_offset(offset), m_a(0) {}

    int operator=( int a );
    operator int() const;

    int m_a;
    const uint8_t m_offset;

};

int Prop::operator=( int a ) { 
   Super * super = (Super *)( ((char *)this) + m_offset); 
   super->onSet(); m_a = a; return a; 
}

struct Super {

    // assuming exact order of properties
    Super() : one(0), two(sizeof(Prop)) {}

    void onSet() { printf("set"); }
    void onGet() { printf("get"); }

    Prop one;  
    Prop two;

};
```

Since this offset is a constant expression it (theoretically) can be kept in ROM (or at least it can be smaller than sizeof(pointer)).

Or maybe there is another way?

Comment: You don't need (or use) Super for the get or set action.

Comment: @stark eehmm.. how? If I need to call non-static method of the Super on get/set action, how can I do it without pointer to Super object?

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, show a `Super` that uses your proposal, Regardless, the standard doesn't support addressing an object from its composed members in the fashion you're proposing, save for the *first* member, who's address is guaranteed to be that of the composing outer object. (e.g. the zero-offset member).

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry, could you please clarify what you want me to show?

Comment: @WhozCraig 'the standard doesn't support addressing an object from its composed members' well, that's a pity. Do you know a specific clause for this?

Comment: I can't see how I can make it any clearer. You showed a `Super` using your `Prop` implementation in your first source list, but no `Super` using the proposed `Prop` implementation in your *second* source list. I'm curious to see how that would look. I.e. what are you initializing your members with (the value you're passing as offsets), especially considering what `(this + m_offset)` actually does in a `Prop` member ; think about that.

Comment: @WhozCraig oh, that. That's easy `Super() : one(0), two(sizeof(Prop)) {}` - assuming that Super is generated and all offsets are known, so Super has only `Prop one; Prop two;` value members in this exact order.

Comment: The pointer arithmetic alone should tell you `two(sizeof(Prop))` stands no chance of working, and is rife with UB once you try manufacturing an object pointer out of `(Super *)(this + m_offset)` within a `Prop`.

Comment: It looks like the word "property" is causing some confusion perhaps it should've been explained a bit. A property is a public data member of a class, which can be accessed by client code. And the owning object receives a notification (in the form of `get/set` notification callback) whenever the client code reads or modifies the property.

Comment: @WhozCraig hmm, you mean I need to adjust offset because of alignment of Props inside Super? I believe that can be done by code generator as well. Or there is some other problem?

Comment: @IgorG I assumed that property is wide known term. I guess I'll add a clarification.

Comment: @WhozCraig oh, right, sorry, that was a quick-and-dirty example code; I need to do an additional cast to `char *`

Comment: I'm telling you, that's playing with fire. Forget firing members; just take your proposal and print some *addresses*. Make a `Super` with 3-4 `Prop` members. Print its address. Then print the contrived address of the thing you *think* is the containing `Super` using your offset mechanics in your assignment operator. The only one that will "work" will be the first Prop member (offset 0) and even that won't work if its not the first actual member variable of your Super (add a simple `int` member as the first member of Super to see what I mean).

Comment: @WhozCraig can you explain why this won't work? Offset of a struct member shall be a sum of all previous data member sizes with account for their alignment, shall it not?

Comment: Did you do what I suggested in my prior comment ?

Comment: @WhozCraig the exact method of getting pointer to Super from properties `this` is not much of an interest for me right now. I want to know if standard allows for such a cast at all, assuming the address is correct. Or, if it's not, what else can be done.

Comment: Well, sure. And if you calculate the address correctly, you're not doing anything bad like violating type aliasing. It will take hard casts, but if you get the addresses correct. its viable. That was my only biach about the code you presented. Your calculations were completely off. To do what you want you need a reliable mans to get your `Super`'s address. If you have that, you're in the game. You didn't have that; darune has a nice answer that can deliver it, though I'm not convinced it's worth the headache in the long run; that call is left to you.

Comment: @WhozCraig fair enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### c++ has properties as language extension

Look no further, `msvc` [has support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/property-cpp?view=vs-2019).

`clang` compiler also supports this syntax. Im not sure about `gcc`.

### Storing offset can be also be done

Just, in the constructor calculate the offset from `this`, ala. :

```
Prop( Super& super ) {
  uint8_t offset = this - std::addressof(super );//somewhat unmaintable - but may save some bytes
}
```

then when used, calculate back using `this`

Please note the space saving may be less than it seems due to alignment and padding.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use language extensions. Calculating an offset from a ctor is a nice idea, thank you :) Obviously it'll need additional checks to make sure that offset will fit in uint8.

Comment: Thanks for updating this. the reversal of the difference calculation makes this viable. Not advisable, but viable nonetheless. Further, this will work intermixed with non-Prop members. Frankly the space savings is nominal (with typical padding the OP will save a whopping ONE byte in the presented example `Prop`, at least on most x86 implementations, five bytes on x64).

Comment: @WhozCraig Good point about alignment - ive added a note about that

Comment: @WhozCraig I think savings can be made bigger with `packed` attribute - although it's a language extension as well, it's more widely supported one (or I should say 'my compiler supports it' :).

Comment: @Amomum they're declared members. unless you'r trying to squeeze code down to fit in an 256KB RLL encoder or some other archaic entity frankly I don't see the payoff, but I don't have to; you do, and that's all that really matters. This answer is solid, btw, and at least worthy of uptick if not outright selection.

Comment: @WhozCraig actually, I'm considering using this on microcontroller where typical RAM size is less than 100 KB. On other matters you are correct.

Comment: @Amomum 100KB and you're not just writing in asm ? That's pretty impressive. Best of luck. I loved hardware coding. Man, I really miss that. Long , long time ago.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks :) It's not that hard, actually. My typical project uses about 30 KB of RAM and is still written in C++. Asm is reserved for really hardcore cases.

Answer (score 0):

I obviously don't know the context of your code, so this may be inconceivable in your specific implementation, but you could do something like

```
class Prop(){
  Prop() : m_a(0){};
  int operator=(int a){m_a = a;};
  int m_a;
}

class Super(){
public:
  int set_prop(int index, int value){
    m_props[index] = value;
    onSet();
    return value;
  }
private:
  void onSet(){};
  std::vector<Prop> m_props;
}
```

Obviously you need to initialize the vector and handle error cases etc but the logic is there - if you only access the `prop`s through the `super`.

That leaves you with purely the size of the sequence of structs with no pointers back to the `super`.

Comment: You propose to access properties by index? That kinda beats the whole point of a property - it's supposed to look like an ordinary value member.

Comment: I see you added some additional description to your original question, which does indeed make my solution somewhat "misguided" if you will. I had understood the question to simply be regarding storing data of any kind inside a superclass, with a reference to the super class.